# Primary Key doesn't work at Tag Table in Machbase

Tags: database, time-series, primary-key

I create the table as below, set the primary key as the [document indicated](https://machbase.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/M67E/pages/369919839/Creation+and+Dropping+of+Tag+table).

```
create tagdata table tt1 (name varchar(20) primary key, time datetime basetime, value double summarized) metadata (type short, create_date varchar(10)) ;
```

And I executed 2 inserts with same primary key, as below:

```
insert into tt1 values ('aaa', '2010-01-01', 123);
insert into tt1 values ('aaa', '2010-01-01', 222);
```

When I try to check the result, it reveals that primary key doesn't work at all.

How could this be possible??

[image]

What's more: [the doc](https://machbase.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/M75ME/pages/473600625/Volatile+Table) indicates that only `volatile table` and `lookup table` are able to set `primary key`, but obviously `tag table` could make it as well.